# Pointer changes for apparently no reason - C

Tags: c, list, function, pointers

I have a school assignment to create a database of sorts in C, where I can read from a file or keyboard, but the databse itself is stored in memory.

Now, I won't ask for help directly with the assignment, but as I am new to C, I don't understand why this snipped of code I wrote is not working.

part of the source file, supposed to add a student to the linked list.

Wanted to add these here, I do set the innitial value to NULL.

---

```
struct student *student_root = NULL;
struct teacher *teacher_root = NULL;

    void add_student(char *name) {
    if (student_root == NULL) { //if there is no student in the list

        /* Allocate memory equivalent to the size of struct student
        and store the address in student_root */
        student_root = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
        // ^ this is something I tried to do to fix it, but I think it is not needed

        struct student new; //creating the student root
        inn_student(&new); //innitializing the root
        student_root = &new;
        set_sn(student_root, 1);//sn = student number, like an ID
        set_student_name(student_root, name);

        student_out(*student_root);this works here
    }
    else {
        struct student new; //creating the student that is to be added
        inn_student(&new); //innitializing the student that is to be added

        set_student_name(&new, name);

        printf("%d\n", student_root->student_number);//when I do this, I get a random number instead of '1'
        set_next_student(student_root, &new); // adding the new student to the list (student number is added automatically)
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the first time I insert, the student_root pointer is working, it is pointing at the 'new' student struct. . . but when I add something else, it doesn't work. Could the 'new' struct be getting forgotten in memory after the function is done? If so, how to fix that ?

Comment: `struct student new;` : `new` is local variable in `add_student` function. It becomes invalid outside the function scope.

Comment: That statement does not copy the 'local' student instance into to the previously allocated memory as you might think it does: `student_root = &new;` So the ` student_root` points to memory that is not yours after you leave the function.

Comment: It is very important to understand what the lifetime of an object is if you're going to start stashing pointers to it!

Comment: Also, the "create a new student/initialize/assign number" code is duplicated in both conditions. Do that outside the `if`, and let the `if` determine only how to add the new student to the list.

Comment: Try to avoid using `new` as variable name

Comment: Mega-dupe.  Many, many examples on SO of this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
student_root = malloc(sizeof(struct student));

struct student new; //creating the student root
inn_student(&new); //innitializing the root
student_root = &new;
```

After you initialize the `student_root` to point to a heap location, a few lines down you set it again to point to an automatic local variable whose memory will be rewritten by other code when you return from this function.

The correct way is to initialize the fields of the `inn_student(student_root)`, instead of `inn_student(&new)`.

Comment: I edited my post.  No need to use an automatic variable `new` once you allocated space in heap for student_root.

Comment: No, you have to `memcopy` the content of the local variable `new` on the stack to your previously allocated heap memory in `student_root` instead of
 just assigning pointers.

Comment: Yess, it worked ! For those that have a similar problem this is  the fixed code.
`/* Allocate memory equivalent to the size of struct student
  and store the address in student_root */
  student_root = malloc(sizeof(struct student));


  struct student new; //creating the student root

  inn_student(&new); //innitializing the root

  *student_root = new; //instead of setting the pointer to the struct that will be automatically deleted, the student_root gets a copy of the data`
------
I tried to make it look nice but I can't :c

Comment: Alternatively, the code would work as intended by changing the third statement from `student_root = &new` to `*student_root = new`.    That changes the dynamically allocated object and, when `new` passes out of scope, it ceases to exist.

Comment: Ah, ok. So the 'new' object just gets lost after the program leaves the function. I am trying the memcpy function to transfer the data from one to the other.

Comment: @StefanHorvath As @Peter said, `*student_root = new` is also correct, `memcpy` copies also the padding bits, which are not useful.